# Flickr photo upload

Tags: android, flickr, photo-upload

I am facing a problem regarding uploading image on flickr. I have used Oauth1.0 for authenticating user and then want to post the image but unable to post it. Can anybody suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

See how FlickrFree for Android does exactly this in [RestClient.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch#eyXbqyWrpnQ/trunk/src/com/zmosoft/flickrfree/RestClient.java&q=upload%20package%3ahttp://flickrfree%5C.googlecode%5C.com)